# Can't get center LatLng using BlazorGoogleMaps component after map moved

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorgooglemaps

I'm using the rungwiroon/BlazorGoogleMaps component in my Blazor project and am trying to get the map LatLng after the user drags the map to a different location, but for the life of me can't work out how to access the LatLng of the new center of the map.

```
private async Task OnAfterInitAsync() {
    await map1.InteropObject.AddListener("dragend", OnDragEnd);
}
```

But then in my OnDragEnd method I don't know how to access the new location attributes. I've inspected the 'map1' object and tried lots of random methods on 'map1.InteropObject' but can't seem to find anything.

The project is here if it helps:
https://github.com/rungwiroon/BlazorGoogleMaps/tree/master
And there are some examples (but not much detail) here: https://github.com/rungwiroon/BlazorGoogleMaps/blob/master/ClientSideDemo/Pages/MapEvents.razor

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `await map1.GetCenter();`

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting 'GoogleMap does not contain a definition for GetCenter()' etc.

Comment: Got it - it's await map1.InteropObject.GetCenter(). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You are correct. I saw [this](https://github.com/rungwiroon/BlazorGoogleMaps/blob/a611978d5c7dabeb30a7e0356a8888586988f5dd/ServerSideDemo/Pages/Maps.razor#L73) sample where instead of the `<GoogleMap>` component it uses a simple div and a `Map` object ref directly. In all other samples it uses the `<GoogleMap>` component and a `GoogleMap` object ref and you need to use the `InteropObject` property to get the `Map` object.